# javascript function not called signalr hub method

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

```
   <code> 
      `public void SendChat()       
            {
              var clients = Clients.All;
         clients.sendchat();
          }`  
        </code>
```

it's hub method

```
      <code>      ` var chat = $.connection.echo;
          chat.client.sendchat = function () {
         console.log("signalR work!"); };`

     </code>
```

it's client method

```
     <code>
        $('#sendMessage').click(function () {
      $.ajax({             type: 'POST',
                           url: '/InboxUI/SendMessage',
                           data: { friendId: friend, message: text },
                           success: function (sendDate) {
                          date = sendDate.toLocaleString('tr-TR', { timeZone: 
            'UTC' });} }).done(function () {
           hub.server.sendChat();});
    });

     </code>
```

it's server method
this sendChat method not called echoHub's sendchat method!
Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Read tutorial**
According your code I suggest you to start with the tutorial on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server

Why you make an ajax call? Where did you start the connection?... With signalr you should first start the connection to the server. After that you can send messages in both directions.

**2. Samplecode**

According the following sample from the previous link you can make a step forward:

*Serverpart:*

```
public class ContosoChatHub : Hub
{
    public void NewContosoChatMessage(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
    }
}
```

*Client part:*

```
var contosoChatHubProxy = $.connection.contosoChatHub;
// Define the methods which the client can call on the server. (Must be befor start!)
contosoChatHubProxy.client.addContosoChatMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
    console.log(userName + ' ' + message);
};
// Important you must start the connection
$.connection.hub.start()
    .done(function(){
     console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + $.connection.hub.id);            
     })
    .fail(function(){ console.log('Could not Connect!'); });

// You can call also method from client on server like (Connection must be established first!):
contosoChatHubProxy.server.newContosoChatMessage({ UserName: userName, Message: message}).done(function () {
        console.log ('Invocation of NewContosoChatMessage succeeded');
    }).fail(function (error) {
        console.log('Invocation of NewContosoChatMessage failed. Error: ' + error);
    });
```